# How to disable DEBUG messages from Spring boot without using xml config?

Tags: java, spring, logging

Is there a way to disable DEBUG logging when running an application using Spring boot?

This is how I create the context:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
```

I can only find example for XML Spring config files.
I am not using any XML, but a config class (SpringConfig.class) where I create all the required @beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application.properties set to off log.

```
logging.level.root=OFF
```

Check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels)

Comment: Is there a way to specify this in Spark?
Let's assume I want to disable only Spark logging.

Comment: I don't know what is the package for spark, but suppose that is com.spark, then you need set to logging.level.com.spark=OFF